# Cannot set z-index on Angular UI dropdown-menu inside ng-grid

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

The problem is I cannot get dropdown menu to show on top of ng-grid. I've even tried manually setting the z-index property on every element via FireBug but still cannot get it to work.

I'm hoping someone with similar experience can help..

Here's [Plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/6U9Yu4Dy7b9gu3gij1qI?p=preview)

Comment: This is not possible by the way the parent elements are positioned.
You might want to take a look [at this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Answer (score 2):

It kinda works if you set:

```
.ngViewport {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

in style.css. But it does not look very nice. May be take this [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RVjFb7p3I3gwuo272OoZ?p=preview) as a base for further experiments.

Comment: Thanks mainguy. I tried that also but I'm not going go to forward with ng-grid as it has many flaws.. I'll work on it but not gonna use it for production code :(